# Selecting rows with a NON-distinct foreign key

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table 'pages' that looks like this:

```
id  | title | menu_id
 1    'foo'      1
 2    'bar'      1
 3    'baz'      2
```

I'm trying to select rows whose menu_id is NOT distinct. In this example, the query should return only the first two rows. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
select title, menu_id from tableName group by menu_id having count(menu_id) > 1
```

Comment: If there's no way to return all rows (instead of just the first row for each non-distinct menu_id) in one query, then this will work. Thanks.

Comment: @Chiraag Mundhe: The query above should return all rows that have same foreign key more than once :)